# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined - Scrolling error?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
   <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#home" title="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="signup.html" title="">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="signin.html" title="">Sign in</a></li>                
</ul>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var ssSmoothScroll = function() {
    $('.smoothscroll').on('click', function (e) {
        var target = this.hash,
        $target    = $(target);

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();        

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, cfg.scrollDuration, 'swing').promise().done(function () {
           // check if menu is open
           if ($('body').hasClass('menu-is-open')) {
               $('#header-menu-trigger').trigger('click');
           }

           window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
};
```

I trawled through several answers to this and still cannot find why mine isn't working. Any help is much appreciated.

I want to continue on to either signup.html or signin.html but neither of the links work if I click them. They only work if I right click and open in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will return `undefined` is if you call it on an empty jQuery set. So that tells us that `$(target)` is returning an empty jQuery set, presumably because `target` contains a selector that doesn't match any elements.

You probably want to add a guard to allow for that:

```
if (!$target.length) {
    return;
}
```

...just after `$target = ...`.

---

Looking at your HTML, though: You probably just want to remove the `smoothscroll` class from the links that take you to another page (the second two in your example). The only purpose they seem to have is to make jumping to anchors within the page scroll rather than jump. Since those links are off-page, I'd just not put the class on them in the first place.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! I absolutely suck at this, how will that redirect me to either the signup.html or signin.html? Probably a really stupid question but I'm brand new to this :( what do I need to return exactly

Comment: @todotwo: Not a stupid question. By not doing `e.preventDefault()`, we don't stop the default action of clicking a link, which is to follow it. But why would you want the `smoothscroll` class on those links in the first place? (I should have looked more closely at the HTML before answering.)